# Optimizing run-time over two functions

Tags: r, performance, runtime

I am still new to this R, and I have written two functions that are taking a long time to run. I've tried to optimize as much as I can, but haven't been able to shave a lot of time off.

What I want to do is to make a function to estimate two parameters, such that the function `kvasum` is minimized. I suspect my problem is in the loop in the buttom. I have quite a lot of observations and would like to run this with different parameters.

```
# Generate Data
x <- runif(1000)
vpk <- data.frame(x);
names(vpk) <-'V1'
n <- 20000000

# This function takes the mean squared errors of the vpk vector and the convergence rate 
#The function therefore returns a value
#The NA's have been omitted here

kvasum = function(par){
  q <- (log(vpk$V1) / log(1 / n) - (-1+(par[1]+1/par[2])) )
  q <- q[!is.na(q)]
  ((10 - 0) / 1000) * sum(q^2)
}


#The function optim has been used to find alpha and beta such that kvasum is minimized. 
#To be sure it is a global minumum, different starting parameters has been tried using a for loop. 
#The starting values, the value of the function and the parameter estimates has been saved in a vector r 
r <- matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 10000000)
t = 1
for(a in seq(from = 0.01, to = 5,by = 0.01)){
  for(b in seq(from = 0.01, to = 1.99, by = 0.01)){
    h <- optim(par = c(a, b), kvasum, method = 'L-BFGS-B', lower = c(0.0000001, 0.0000001), upper=c(5, 1.999999))
    t <- 1+t
    r[t,] <- c(a, b, h$value, h$par)
  }
}
```

Comment: If I did my math correctly, this is an trivial optimization. You are essentially optimizing something that is proportional to `sum(vector^2-2(Beta(Alpha+1)+(Alpha+1)^2)/Beta^2)` The global min is at `c(0, 1)` There is really no need to loop through all the starting conditions to check if your solution is the global min.

Comment: I have simplified the expression in kvasum, because I am replicating an article that is not yet published.